# What is a valid source/destination changeset?

Tags: sandbox, change-set, production

What is a valid source and destination pair that can send/receive change sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three basic combinations: production to sandbox, sandbox to sandbox, and sandbox to production. Any combination is allowed, so long as the orgs are configured to accept incoming change sets, and any sandboxes involved are created from the same production org.

Comment: and all the sandboxes originated from the same PROD org

Comment: Thanks. I did mean to put that in. I've updated this answer to reflect that.